# How do I change an UI/Image when there's 2 gameobjects with the same name?

Tags: json, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm developing an application for the hololens that generates multiple canvases with a panel with UI/Image elements. I have 1 JSON string:

```
{  
   "PC_Station":[  
      {  
         "PLC_0":{  
            "DB1":{  
               "test123":0
            },
            "STOP":false,
            "Frap":false,
            "START":false,
            "Start_1":false,
            "Stop_1":false,
            "Led1":true,
            "Led2":false,
            "Led3":true,
            "Counter":4002,
            "Sliderval":0
         }
      },
      {  
         "PLC_1":{  
            "DB1":{  
               "test123":55
            },
            "STOP":false,
            "START":false,
            "Start_1":false,
            "Stop_1":false,
            "Led1":true,
            "Led2":false,
            "Led3":true,
            "Counter":4002,
            "Sliderval":0
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

This JSON string has 2 JSON objects inside a JSON array called PLC_1 and PLC_0. PLC_1 has the same variables as PLC_0.

I've made the following function that appends the JSON and changes the color of the UI/Image objects:

```
IEnumerator updateTags()
    {
        string json = "{\"PC_Station\": [{\"PLC_1\": {\"DB1\": {\"test123\": 30}, \"STOP\": false, \"START\": true, \"Start_1\": false, \"Stop_1\": true, \"Led1\": false, \"Led2\": false, \"Led3\": false, \"Counter\": 3880, \"Sliderval\": 60}}]}";
        string json1 = "{\"PC_Station\": [{\"PLC_0\": {\"DB1\": {\"test123\": 0}, \"STOP\": false,\"Frap\": false, \"START\": false, \"Start_1\": false, \"Stop_1\": false, \"Led1\": true, \"Led2\": false, \"Led3\": true, \"Counter\": 4002, \"Sliderval\": 0}},{\"PLC_1\": {\"DB1\": {\"test123\": 55}, \"STOP\": false, \"START\": false, \"Start_1\": false, \"Stop_1\": false, \"Led1\": true, \"Led2\": false, \"Led3\": true, \"Counter\": 4002, \"Sliderval\": 0}}]}";
        var data = JToken.Parse(json1);
        while (true)
        {
            foreach (var value in data)
            {
                foreach(JArray arr in value)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in arr[i])
                        {
                            var itemproperties = item.Parent;
                            foreach (JToken token in itemproperties)
                            {
                                var prop = token as JProperty;
                                var plc = (JObject)prop.Value;
                                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> val in plc)
                                {
                                    if(val.Value is JObject)
                                    {
                                        JObject nestedobj = (JObject)val.Value;
                                        foreach (JProperty nestedvariables in nestedobj.Properties())
                                        {
                                            string varkey = nestedvariables.Name;
                                            string varvalue = nestedvariables.Value.ToString();
                                            GameObject test = GameObject.Find(varkey+"value");
                                            test.GetComponent<Text>().text = varvalue;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        for(int v = 0; v < abc.Count; v++)
                                        {
                                            Debug.Log(v);
                                            foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> variab in abc[v])
                                            {
                                                string varkey = val.Key;
                                                string varvalue = val.Value.ToString();
                                                GameObject test = GameObject.Find(varkey);
                                                if(varvalue == "True")
                                                {
                                                    test.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.green;
                                                }
                                                if(varvalue == "False")
                                                {
                                                    test.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.red;
                                                }
                                                if(varvalue != "True" && varvalue != "False")
                                                {
                                                    GameObject text = GameObject.Find(varkey + "value");
                                                    text.GetComponent<Text>().text = varvalue;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        }
    }
```

When I run the programme, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the function properly adds color to the UI/Images.

Now, for my question:

How can I make it so that the UI/Images on both canvases get filled with color despite having the same name?

Comment: Can you post the hierarchy view of these canvases?

Comment: Oh right, that would be: Canvas(es) - Panel - multiple Images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it by using transform.find. I used it to find items in the hierarchy.
The code now functions like I want it to.

[image]

First I make a new gameobject:

```
public GameObject upd4;
```

Then I use it in my code as follows:

```
upd4 = transform.Find("Canvas" + i + "/Panel/" + plcvvobj.Key + "/" + plcvvobj.Key + "value").gameObject;
```

BTW, my hierarchy is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are no obvious solutions as GameObject referenes do not serialize easily, you couls reference objects by their position in the current branch of the tree (transform.GetSiblingIndex()) but that will not work if you move stuff around.
You could also just rename your objects.